# Why is MySQL not converting my data correctly?

Tags: mysql

I have a column of decimals, but MySQL is reading them as TEXT. I tried this to alter the column by:

```
ALTER TABLE `engine_type_project`.`weo_data_eu_test` 
CHANGE COLUMN `Mean_GDP_all_time` `Mean_GDP_all_time` DECIMAL(6,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

An original value is: 3,282.772

But my code returns it as: 3.00

Prior to this, I attempted:

```
SELECT CAST('Mean_GDP_all_time' AS DECIMAL(6,2))
FROM weo_data_eu_test;
```

But the entire column returned as 0.00

Comment: N.B.: Values with a precision of 5 and scale of 2 are returning the correct decimals in the same column (e.g. 778.737 converts into 778.74)

Comment: Did you try to enter values as 3,282.772 with the comma thousands separator? MySQL numeric literals don't support that. Take out the comma.

Comment: The problem isn't the datatype, it's the code that tries to insert into the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In casting non-numeric values to numeric, mysql does not expect commas.  So it gives up looking for additional parts of the number after the "3".

Before changing the type, remove the commas with:

```
update weo_data_eu_test set Mean_GDP_all_time=replace(Mean_GDP_all_time,',','')
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f98d09cf04028b24dc637ca70322b8b)